# Working with mathematic special characters in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, matplotlib, unicode

I am extracting some values from a ASCII file in Python, which I want to use for labels in a plot, using the matplotlib. So one of the strings is `µm/m`. The extracted value inside the Python string is `\xb5m/m` but using the debugger inside Eclipse it looks like `�m/m`.

So when passing the label to the matplotlib, it shows me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So it seems like an encoding problem. I tried adding the following line to the top of my class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Unfortunatelly this doesn't solve the problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *latin-1* encoded not utf-8, you can decode:

```
In [41]: s = "\xb5m/m"

In [42]: print(s)
�m/m

In [43]: print(s.decode("latin-1"))
µm/m
```